# $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ non-zero, they have the same norm if and only if exists $c_1,c_2\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $z_1=c_1c_2$ and $z_2=c_1\bar{c}_2$

Tags: complex-numbers

Given $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ non-zero, they have the same norm if and only if exists $c_1,c_2\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $z_1=c_1c_2$ and $z_2=c_1\bar{c}_2$

The second part i think its easy because if $z_1=c_1c_2$ and $z_2=c_1\bar{c}_2$ then
$|z_2|=|c_1\bar{c}_2|=|c_1||\bar{c}_2|=|c_1||c_2|=|c_1c_2|=|z_2|$ but im stuck in the if i mean $\implies$ any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Write $z_1=re^{i\theta}, z_2=re^{i\phi}$  ($r>0$, $\theta, \phi$ real). Define $c_1=re^{i\frac {\theta+\phi} 2}$, $c_2=e^{i\frac {\theta-\phi} 2}$. Check that this works.

Answer (score 0):

Add $z_1= c_1c_2, z_2 = c_1\bar{c_2}$, we have
$$z_1+z_2 = 2c_1\Re(c_2) $$
Let $2\Re(c_2) = k$, we have $$c_1 = \frac{z_1+z_2}{k}$$
and $$c_2 = \frac{z_1}{c_1}= \frac{\bar{z_2}}{\bar {c_1}}$$
Check that $\frac{z_1}{c_1}= \frac{\bar{z_2}}{\bar {c_1}}$.